# How to use multiple color in donut chart of amcharts?

Tags: jquery, html, css, amcharts

I want to give 2 colors in a donut chart which will make gradient fill as the background color in [amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/).

I have found the solution for gradient color with a single color, but how can I give a gradient color with more than one color?

[Current Donut chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2xkE.png)

[Resulted Donut chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eum2P.png)

Here is my code:

```
 var chart5 = AmCharts.makeChart( "emp-hour-chartContainer1", {
                "type": "pie",
                "theme": "light",
                "dataProvider": chartEmpData1,
                "titleField": "title",
                "valueField": "value",
                "labelRadius": -21,
                "radius": "50%",
                "innerRadius": "50%",
                "alpha": 1,
                "fontSize": 12,
                "color": "#ffffff",
                "labelText": "[[title]] Days",
                "balloonText": "[[title]] Days",
                "colors":["#f7b72f","#02aace"],
                "export": {
                    "enabled": true
                },
                "allLabels": [{
                    "y": "45%",
                    "align": "center",
                    "size": 15,
                    "text": "Work",
                    "color": "#262727"
                }]
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a gradient to the slices by defining a [`gradientRatio`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSlicedChart#gradientRatio), for example:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("...", {
  // ...
  gradientRatio: [-.4, 0, .2], //negative = darker gradient, positive = lighter gradient
  // ...
});
```

Demo:

```js
var chartEmpData1 = [{title: 13, value: 13}, {title: 25, value: 25}]
var chart5 = AmCharts.makeChart("emp-hour-chartContainer1", {
  type: "pie",
  theme: "light",
  dataProvider: chartEmpData1,
  titleField: "title",
  valueField: "value",
  gradientRatio: [-.4, 0, .2],
  labelRadius: -21,
  radius: "50%",
  innerRadius: "50%",
  alpha: 1,
  fontSize: 12,
  color: "#ffffff",
  labelText: "[[title]] Days",
  balloonText: "[[title]] Days",
  colors: ["#f7b72f", "#02aace"],
  export: {
    enabled: true
  },
  allLabels: [
    {
      y: "45%",
      align: "center",
      size: 15,
      text: "Work",
      color: "#262727"
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
#emp-hour-chartContainer1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="emp-hour-chartContainer1"></div>
```

Comment: I used this solution, but can not get the resulted graph. Thanks for your  help.

Comment: Your only other option is to use SVG filters, though you have to enable `addClassNames`. See [this article](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/svg-filters/).